# How to prevent files and directories in my website from DIRECT URL ACCESS?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory

I have a problem that I can't solve. I have installed a wordpress theme. Now I  added a statement into the .htaccess to prevent directory listing, so when someone writes a direct url to a directory he gets a blank page same as if he writes a direct url to a .php file. My problem is that I want him to redirect him into the home page or to a 404 custom page instead of a blank page. because blank page tells him that this directory or file exists but it is blocked out from him.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+.+/($|\ |\?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+.+\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```

Comment: this is my current .htaccess
<Files wp-config.php>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

Options All -Indexes

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options -Indexes

Comment: when I tried what you wrote on localhost it worked. but when tried it on live server I got stucked in a loop and the website became too heavy